# Content type hub publishing name conflict

Tags: office-365, content-type, content-type-hub

I was doing a migration and consolidated site collections into one site.

I also migrated some custom content types to a new content type hub, before migrating content I thought I had published/subscribed to all CTs from the hub but must have missed one. The migration process created a content type in the site collection and when I realised my mistake in the content type hub (saw that it hadn't been published) I clicked Publish however I now get the error in Pre-import Check

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync.ContentTypeSyndicationException] [Content type name 'ContentTypeA' conflict ]
```

Is there a way to force subscribe to this content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the CT before you can subscribe to it.

You could try to rename it and see if that works. But that will not help you with any migrated data, since that would still point to the old one. Are the CT-ID's different of both CT'S?

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much, we haven't gone live yet so will delete all migrated data, delete the content type in the site collection, subscribe and then do a full migration again

Comment: I love folks who actually test before going live ;) Life can be so much easier if you do that

Comment: Yeah! Was hoping to just have to do an incremental sync instead of a full migration again, oh well